# SpecFlow feature tests are not added to the Visual Studio 2019 Test Explorer window

Tags: testing, nunit, bdd, specflow

I installed from Nugget Package Specflow, Specflow.NUnit, Nunit and Nunit3TestAdapter, and I already intalled too the extension for Visual Studio for Specflow a NUnitTestAdapter, but I can't see the test in TestExplorer window, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Install the SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation/
- Install the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowForVisualStudio
- Make sure Tools > SpecFlow > Legacy > Use SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator Custom Tool is False
- Right click on each feature file and make sure **Custom Tool** is blank. It used to be SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator in SpecFlow 2.x.

More info: [Generating code behind files using MS Build](https://specflow.org/2019/generating-code-behind-files-using-msbuild/).

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing  the Nugget package SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation with the same version than specflow and now I can see the test in TestExplorer, other ways not works for me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you meant to comment on Greg's answer, but have posted as another answer instead. Please post as a comment if you want Greg to be notified.